# Understanding parse() behaviour

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust from The Book, I'm at the end of the Chapter 3, and trying to implement the Farenheit-Celsius conversion, I've encountered this error while compiling this code:

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut farenheit = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut farenheit)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let farenheit: f64 = farenheit.trim().parse();
    conversion(farenheit);
}

fn conversion(farenheit: f64) {
    let celsius = (farenheit - 32.0) / 1.8;
    println!("Farenheit: {farenheit} - Celsius: {celsius}");
}
```

The error is this:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:26
   |
10 |     let farenheit: f64 = farenheit.trim().parse();
   |                    ---   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `f64`, found `Result<_, _>`
```

If I add `.expect("")` after `.parse()` it executes well. I'm not understanding why tho. Expect() shouldn't be just a facultative method to use to handle exceptions?

Comment: Read on, [chapter 9](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) is on error handling with `Result` and friends

Comment: `parse` returns a `Result` because it can fail.

Answer (score 3):

The error you encountered is because the `parse` method on a string returns a `Result` type, specifically `Result<f64, ParseFloatError>`. The Result type in Rust is an `enum` that can either be `Ok(T)` with a value of type T representing success or `Err(E)` with an error of type E representing a failure.

In your code, when you write:

```
let farenheit: f64 = farenheit.trim().parse();
```

You are attempting to assign the result of the parse method directly to a `f64`, which is a `type mismatch`. The parse method returns a `Result`, not a `f64`.

To handle the possibility of a parsing error, you should use the `expect` method or some other error handling mechanism to explicitly handle the Result. Here's how you can do it with `expect`:

```
let farenheit: f64 = farenheit.trim().parse().expect("Failed to parse as f64");
```

In this case, if the parsing fails, it will panic with the provided error message. You can replace "Failed to parse as f64" with a more informative error message if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

What @Joshua says, of course.

I just wanted to add that `expect()`/`unwrap()` are in some cases the correct solution (like when you unwrap something you already know will always succeed), but it is most certainly not the correct way of handling an error in this case.

The reason is that you don't have any control over what the user enters - and hence you should properly handle this error.

Possible ways that come to my mind are `match` or the `?` operator to pass the error up in the call chain.

Here's a solution with `match`:

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut fahrenheit = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut fahrenheit)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    match fahrenheit.trim().parse() {
        Ok(fahrenheit) => conversion(fahrenheit),
        Err(err) => println!("Parsing error: {}", err),
    }
}

fn conversion(fahrenheit: f64) {
    let celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) / 1.8;
    println!("Fahrenheit: {fahrenheit} - Celsius: {celsius}");
}
```

```
$ cargo run
abc
Parsing error: invalid float literal
```